# Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying react-native for the first time and trying to create a stack navigation, I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js"
```

This is mu package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation/stack@": "^5.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm using expo cli to fire up my application.

Comment: `"react-navigation/stack@": "^5.7.0"` looks wrong `"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0"` If this isn't work. please share code of app.js as well, were u are calling the stack

Comment: ```"react-navigation/stack@"``` I don't think that's right, it should've been ```"@react-navigation/stack"```

Answer (score 1):

You have `react-navigation/stack@` installed, and are trying to import `@react-navigation/stack`.

Remove `react-navigation/stack@`, since it's not the right import, and install `@react-navigation/stack` with `npm install --save @react-navigation/stack`.